# What does Emacs support running in parallel?

Tags: threading

[This link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html) on async processes says that Emacs can start processes that run in parallel. Yet [this link](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NoThreading) says that Emacs doesn't have any actual parallelism. Finally, [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Threads.html) says Emacs supports concurrency, though I guess not the parallel kind.

So what does Emacs support running in parallel, if it supports parallelism at all?

Comment: Managing async processes isn't related to Emacs' concurrency. Indeed, Emacs only supports a limited form of concurrency with Lisp threads. Evaluate `(info "(elisp) Threads"` for more information.

Comment: @aadcg: Consider making your comment an answer. Comments can be deleted at any time, and Q&A needs to stand alone (for search etc.). Thx.

Comment: Async processes started by Emacs are being run by the OS, can be programs written in any language, and are talking to Emacs via OS-provided channels.  Starting and communicating with such processes doesn't require Emacs itself to be doing multiple things concurrently.

Answer (score 3):

Managing async processes isn't related to Emacs' concurrency.

Indeed, Emacs only supports a limited form of concurrency with Lisp threads. Evaluate `(info "(elisp) Threads")` for more information.

Comment: So Emacs is not parallel, but it can create async processes which run in parallel with Emacs, and which communicate with Emacs via OS-defined IPC, e.g. pipes?

Comment: Please note that I'm not sure of anything that follows. Those processes are child processes. If Emacs dies, those processes die as well. By default async processes are controlled by ptys, but pipes can also be used. For more information I suggest evaluating `(info "(elisp) Processes")`.

Answer (score 0):

Although Emacs isn't designed from the ground-up to use multiple CPU's
for its internal operations, it has quite a few options for
non-blocking operations / concurrency and paralellism:

- [url-retrieve](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/url/Retrieving-URLs.html) with callback – this is useful for fetching net
  resources concurrently / without blocking
- [make-process](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html)
  – more generally useful if you have a shell command that you want to
  run concurrently

  - if you just want to interactively run a shell command in the
    background, ending a `M-!` command with `&` will run it async.
    Uses `make-process` under the hood.
- The [async](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async) library –
  starts a whole new Emacs process for a single (typically slow)
  function call – very clean separation, allows passing some data back
  and forth too
- [make-thread](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Threads.html)
  (green threads) – might be useful if you have some elisp operations
  that can be slow, and should run while emacs is otherwise idle. Not much used yet, [possibly buggy](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/05/31/)

The builtin thread library with `make-thread` uses cooperative/green
threads, so it can run elisp while waiting for user-input or external
processes – but if you've got some Emacs operation that's pegging the
CPU, splitting it in two with `make-thread` will still just use the
one CPU.

If you want to use several CPU cores at a time from Emacs, you'll need
to use several processes (so `make-process` or `async`). The same
issue exists in in Python (Global Interpreter Lock) and OCaml before
v5.